Quickly converting a regex into a minimized DFA
Is there some sort of algorithmic way to quickly convert a regex into a minimized DFA? I am able to somehow "guess" the DFA by playing around with the regex (as shown in the image, where the regex is a*b(a|b)), but doing this becomes very hard if the regex is more complicated. An example is (a|b)*a(a|b)(a|b), which creates a very complex minimized DFA.
I already know of methods like Thompson's Construction + Subset Construction, but doing all that takes up a lot of time (where by "time" I mean "time to do it by hand"), so I'd rather avoid it.


Just as an addendum to DW's answer, while there's no quick way in general to convert a RE into a DFA (because of exponential blowup), there is an algebraic way, which is to use Brzozowski derivatives.
We start with the axioms for a Kleene algebra, and then add two operations.
The first operation is evaluation at zero, which is what you get when you substitute all the terminal symbols with the null set, and then simplify.
$$\displaystyle \begin{eqnarray*}(E_1 + E_2)(0) & = & E_1(0) + E_2(0) \\
(E_1\,E_2)(0) & = & E_1(0)\,E_2(0) \\
a(0) & = & 0 \\
E^*(0) & = & 1
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Taking your RE as an example:
$$\displaystyle E = (a + b)^*a(a+b)(a+b)$$
We essentially replace all of the occurrences of $a$ and $b$ with $0$ and then simplify until we get either $0$ or $1$:
$$\displaystyle E(0) = (0 + 0)^*0(0+0)(0+0) = 0$$
The second operation that we add is the Brzozowski derivative, which is a kind of partial derivative on terminal symbols:
$$\displaystyle \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial a}{\partial a} & = & 1 \\
\frac{\partial b}{\partial a} & = & 0 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left(E_1 + E_2\right) & = & \frac{\partial}{\partial a} E_1 + \frac{\partial}{\partial a}E_2 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left(E_1\,E_2\right) & = & E(0) \frac{\partial}{\partial a} E_2 + \frac{\partial}{\partial a}E_1\,E_2 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} E^* & = & \frac{\partial}{\partial a} E\,E^*
\end{eqnarray*}$$
As you can see, this is pretty much the same as the rules for a partial derivative in a differential field. The product rule is a little different because concatenation doesn't commute.
Kleene star is analogous to exponentiation:
$$\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  e^{f(x)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x)\,e^{f(x)}$$
The Brzozowski derivative with respect to $a$ is the set of strings of a RE which begin with the symbol $a$, but with the $a$ removed:
$$\displaystyle \frac{\partial E}{\partial a} = \left\{ w\,|\,aw \in E \right\}$$
Or, to put it another way, if you converted $E$ to a DFA, and then moved the start state to the state at the destination of the transition for $a$ from the start state, then the resulting modified DFA would accept the language $\frac{\partial E}{\partial a}$.
What that means is that you can expand a RE into the equation for its start state:
$$\displaystyle E = E(0) + a\frac{\partial E}{\partial b} + b \frac{\partial E}{\partial b} + \cdots$$
This identity is Taylor's theorem.
The first term is $1$ if the start state is nullable, and $0$ if it is not. The other terms are the transitions. And from this, you can recursively build a DFA in a purely algebraic way.
Moreover, the algebraic approach extends naturally to other operators such as set intersection, set union, and even more exotic operators such as a symmetric product called the interleave product. You just need to define evaluation at zero, and the derivative:
$$\displaystyle \begin{eqnarray*}
(E_1 \times E_2)(0) & = & E_1(0)\,E_2(0) \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left(E_1 \times E_2\right) & = & E_1 \times \frac{\partial}{\partial a} E_2 + \frac{\partial}{\partial a}E_1\times E_2
\end{eqnarray*}$$
The operator is then the "solution" to the resulting "differential equation".

Does using Brzozowski derivatives guarantee that I'll get a minimized DFA in the end?

@Librapulpfiction No. You would have that guarantee if you had an exact RE equality test, but that problem is PSPACE complete.

No.  All known algorithms to convert a regex into a DFA can take exponential time in the worst case.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/165160/755 for a proof.
Standard methods are to use Thompson's algorithm or Glushkov's algorithm and then apply the subset construction.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/165181/755 for other methods.

By "time" I meant "time to do it by hand". I updated the post to reflect that.

@Librapulpfiction, The same lower bound applies to any algorithm, whether executed by hand or on a computer.
